# What are the common misuses of "enum" in C?

Tags: c, enum

I have seen C code where people used enum heavily. But all it does is confuse others. In many places plain integers can do the same thing with less ambiguity. What are the common misuses of enum?

Comment: Why would an int be less ambiguous? I would say that in general, an opaque integer is *more* ambiguous than an enum. Can you give an example?

Comment: @Dean Harding In my case, In some UI code the common practice is to make an enum for each menu. For each menu-item, there will be a enumeration. But their only purpose is to use instead of the index of the menu-item in the UI. Working there, I felt there should be plain integers, not the enums.

Comment: but without that enum, won't everything break if you add a new menu item to the top?

Comment: I am not telling to avoid enum like we avoid `goto`. I am just asking for not misusing it. Like someone is replacing every possible integers with enums and if there are too much enum used in one c source file, it's confusing.

Comment: the problem is that we haven't seen a compelling example of where enum's are worse then plain integers.

Answer (score 7):

One case I can think of, though haven't seen in the wild yet, is to abuse enums as a collection of disjointed integer constants:

```
enum somestuff { days_in_week = 7,
                 months_in_year = 12,
                 number_of_planets = 8,
                 fingers_per_hand = 5 };
```

The most pathological, innocent looking example I can imagine would be

```
enum numbers { one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten };
```

because `one`==0, `two`==1 etc.

Comment: An enum of numbers: Just in case mathematics is redefined you're probably OK! Just change the enum.

Comment: I agree, but enum months { january = 1, feb, march, april, may, ... } is perfectly fine.

Comment: Tim Post: Unless you use `struct tm`, where `tm_mon` is 0..11

Comment: 8 planets? In my heart, Pluto is still a planet. #TeamPluto :)

Comment: splattne: Sure, Pluto is a planet, but this is C, so counting is 0-based. ;-)

Comment: BTW, I possess strong evidence suggesting Pluto's disqualification as a planet was actually a workaround for an off-by-one bug in IAU's planet management system (PMS). Disclosure on Wikileaks will happen the day after March 31st, 2011.

Comment: Gotta upvote for that last example.

Comment: Biggest cringe-maker I've seen in a long time.

Answer (score 6):

The biggest issue I've had with enumerations is them being defined twice.

```
EnumZ
{
    Yes,
    No,
    Maybeso
}
```

and someone else, with a very similar name, would have

```
EnumZee
{
    No,
    Maybeso,
    Yes
}
```

It's not a "quick catch" because that's the enum you made.. right? It's something you don't really see until you're stepping through the code and see that your 'No' is coming back as zero instead of one.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ (would have posted as comment, but for the code this works better)

```
enum ELength
{
   mm = -3, 
   m = 0,
   km = 3,
   // ...
}


double operator*(double d, ELength scale)
{
   return d * pow(10, scale);
}

// allows:
double len = 2*mm;
```

Another applicaiton would be qualifiers:

```
 enum EConstraintMode
 {
    abs   = 1,
    rel   = 2,
    expand = 3,
 };


 struct Constraint
 {
    EConstraintMode mode;
    int value;
 }

 Constraint operator-(EConstraintMode mode, int value)
 {
    Constraint c = { mode, value };
    return c;
 }

 void SetConstraints(Constraint top, Constraint Left,....) { ... }

 SetConstraint(abs-12, rel-50, abs-12, rel-50);
```

I'm still undecided if this is wickedly cool, wickedly horrible, or both. (Wouldn't use that in production code, for that reason).

Comment: oh my word that second example Terrifies me.